# How to access Amazon kinesis streams files in S3 in my pyspark code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am given a bucket on S3 that consists of Kinesis stream files in compressed format using 'snappy'. The folder structure and file format is is `s3://<mybucket>/yyyy/mm/dd/*.snappy`.

I am trying to read this into an `sqlContext` in `pyspark`. Normally, I would specify the bucket as:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json('s3://<mybucket>/inputfile.json')
```

How do I get all these multi-part compressed files into my data frame?

UPDATE: Seems like I made more progress using this same construct. But, running into heap size problems:

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p
kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 6128
kill -9 6128"...
```

The data size is not that big, but somehow this uncompress step seems to make things worse.

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmmm...I was not sure. New to this stuff. Can you not vote to migrate instead of down voting? :)

Comment: @CharlieFish Why exactly does this belong on [sf]? It looks like a question for [so] to me.

Comment: Already flagged it as needing to go into Server Fault. As for the down vote not quite sure why Stack Overflow isn't letting me remove it giving me an error saying my vote is locked in unless the question gets edited.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I could be totally wrong but to me this seems like much more of a server related question instead of programming related question.

Comment: @CharlieFish Perhaps you would care to explain how you came to that conclusion? It isn't at all apparent to me.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry. At first glance it looked like an AWS question not a programming related question. I should look at questions more carefully next time. Didn't see the whole part about pyspark. Sorry about that. Will work to look at questions more carefully next time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton your * pattern at the top with `../*.snappy` would already work. are you getting an error when running it?

Comment: @Kristian Why have you pinged me? I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: @kristian Thank you. That does seem to do something. But, running into errors. Could you please provide any additional advice? Seem my update above to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get all snappy files from all days / months / years, try something like this:

```
s3://<mybucket>/*/*/*/*.snappy
```

Where the first three `*`'s are referring to the `/yyyy/mm/dd/` subfolders.

To prove this works, you can perform the following test:

created a `testDirectories` folder... and inside it, nested some date folders.

```
nestedDirectories/
-- 2016/
-- -- 12/
-- -- -- 15/
-- -- -- -- data.txt
```

and inside the `data.txt`:

```
hello
world
I
Have
Some
Words
```

And then I've run `pyspark`:

```
>>> rdd = sc.readText("/path/to/nestedDirectories/*/*/*/*.txt")
>>> rdd.count()
6
```

So, that star-pattern works for importing files into an RDD.

So, from here, if you have problems with memory and stuff, it may be that you have too many files that are too small of a file size. This is known as the "small files problem" https://forums.databricks.com/questions/480/how-do-i-ingest-a-large-number-of-files-from-s3-my.html

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: I tested this and it works perfectly well with clear text files that are organized into a hierarchical folder structure (ignoring too many files). However, when I have snappy compressed files, the exact same code fails to load the data into Spark (this is on EMR where I believe snappy codec is available in default software). Any thoughts of what might be going on? I am 'this' close. :)